# How to join two files in shell

Tags: linux, shell

There are two files-:

```
File1-:
email
abc@gmail.com
dbc@yahoo.com
hbc@ymail.com

File2-:
abc@gmail.com,dpk,25,India
dbc@yahoo.com,dpk,25,India
hbc@ymail.com,dpk,25,India
kbc@gmail.com,dpk,25,India
nbc@ymail.com,dpk,25,India

Required file should be-:
abc@gmail.com,dpk,25,India
dbc@yahoo.com,dpk,25,India
hbc@ymail.com,dpk,25,India
```

We are not using grep because actual file contains huge data and grepping an email id of file1 in file2 taking huge time.
Is it possible using Join or Comm utility, if yes please help. I had tried but not got desired result also these two utilities works on sort data, but data in two files is not sorted.

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer below as this should clearly fix your problem. If it doesn't, please update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

```
grep -Ff File1 File2
```

This takes the fixed strings (`-F`) from File1 (`-f`) as patterns to grep in File2 for. Grepping for fixed string should speed up operations significantly.

If that doesn't cut it...

```
join -t',' File1 File2
```

...should do as well, but requires both files to be sorted. (Joining on the first field is the default so you only have to tell `join` to use the comma as field delimiter.) If the files really are huge *and* require sorting first, I am not sure this will actually be faster.